# how to change existing website's domain name

Tags: dns, web-hosting

Much to my surprise, it is not a five minutes-task at all. Spent almost a day without achieving anything...

My existing website notgoodname.com is running well for months. And I want to change it to goodnewname.com (already bought it) . Ideally, I would like to do it the way that impact users least (least downtime, 0 data lost), SEO n others are second priority.

Initially, I was thinking about having goodnewname.com and notgoodname.com sharing same IP, same hosting ressource (php code, mysql db), then gradually retire notgoodname.com. However, Googling can't help, godaddy support neither, both gave me confusing guides.

Please lend me some guidance/good links.. (my background: ~10 year as software developer but just few months webmaster : cpanel/WHM/hosting/dns kinda stuff)

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I would like to congratulate you on goodnewname.com, what a find. :P

The easiest hassle free way to use the new domain is to add it as a parked domain under the cPanel account of the existing website, you would also need to change the nameserver to point at WHM's/YourHosts nameservers, or, and a root A record pointing the domain to your web server's IP.

If the website is quite straightforward (PHP, CSS, HTML, no databases etc..) you could instead of adding it as an addon, create another hosting account for the new name, copy all the files across from wwwroot (public_html) on the old account to wwwroot (public_html) on the new account and then delete the old account and add old bad name as an addon.